# Using Perl, how can I replace all whitespace in a file with newlines?

Tags: perl, whitespace, carriage-return

For example text file:

```
    Speak friend and enter
```

using a Perl script to remove whitespace and replace with carriage-return

```
    Speak
    friend 
    and
    enter
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
perl -p -e 's/\s+/\n/g'
```

Answer (score 3):

create a file test.pl:

```
open my $hfile, $ARGV[0] or die "Can't open $ARGV[0] for reading: $!";
while( my $line = <$hfile> )
{
    $line =~ s/\s+/\n/g;
    print $line;
}
close $hfile;
```

then run it like:

```
perl test.pl yourfile.txt
```

or, if you don't want to use a file, you can do it all from the command line like:

```
perl -p -e "s/\s+/\n/g" yourfile.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sed`

```
sed -e "s/[ ]/\n/g"
```

or anything that works with regular expressions

```
"s/[ ]/\n/g"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want inplace editing you can use the -i switch. Check out [perlrun](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html) to see how it's done, but, basically:

```
perl -p -i.bak -e 's/\s+/\n/g'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -l

use strict;
use warnings;

print join "\n", split while <>;
```

Comment: Nice. I can't understand ones which down vote this perfect answer.